# Magento not sending HTTP 404, but HTTP 500 in header response but it’s incorrect

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I am trying to optimise Magento for SEO. I have it included in Google Webmaster Tools, and I have noticed that there are a lot of pages that are labelled withing GWT as server errors, that is, mostly http 500 errors.

So I did some looking into it, and the URLS that google says are HTTP 500 errors, well, I dont think they are supposed to be. Reason I say this is because Magento is calling the 404.phtml template of “Whoops...."… but Google is right, the header sent is http 500.

How do I go about debugging this? Any ideas?

Many thanks for your help!

Ben

Comment: 500 means a misconfigured server, usually with Magento this means bad file permissions. Directories should be 755 and files should be 644. You need to ensure the following is set correctly as well: `chmod -R o+w media var` and `chmod o+w app/etc`. Do you have a sample URL that we can see?

Answer (score 0):

Try visiting the offending pages with a browser that can emulate Googlebot headers (e.g. Firefox with User Agent switcher). This will ensure that the site is responding with the same response that Google is seeing. Also, you will need to enable developer mode and enable error reporting, which you may want to do conditionally based on your IP - this can all be done in *index.php*.

Ensure that you are reviewing the server logs.

Comment: I think there are various issues going on... Check this URL, which is available and found: http://www.e-cocinasplus.com/en/refunds-returns, should be a 200, but gives a 500... then there are others, which products have been removed and URL rewrite management is a mess I am assuming in Magento, e.g, not tracked all the changes, and this should be a 404: http://www.e-cocinasplus.com/en/decor/especial-navidad.html               Then I have other pages, which do give a solid HTTP 500 http://www.e-cocinasplus.com/en/kitchens/knives/wusthof-series.html ... But all of these return a 500 response Help